# Function argument for mysqli field

Tags: php, mysqli

Need to pass through an argument for column header in to function. 
Would like to have ["name"] be an argument in the function so I can pull different fields from sql, Can you please help. Thank you.
Here is the function:

```
 function read_pages_array_2 () {
        global $connection;

        $query  = "SELECT * ";
        $query .= "FROM pages ";
        $query .= "ORDER BY id ASC";
        $result = mysqli_query ($connection, $query);
        confirm_query ($result);
        while($result_use = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo $result_use["name"] . "<br/>";

        }
    }
```

Comment: What part of this are you stuck with?

Comment: Looking for ["name"] to be an argument, so I can change when using function and instead of name, get ["page_id"] or whatever else. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function read_pages_array_2($columnName) {
   global $connection;

   $query  = "SELECT p.".$columnName." FROM pages p ORDER BY id ASC";
   $result = $connection->query($query); // Object Oriented use of connection
   confirm_query($result);
   while ($result_use = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo $result_use[$columnName] . "<br/>";
   }
```

Yes?

Comment: Thank you, let me try this approach.

Answer (score 1):

OP asked

> Looking for ["name"] to be an argument, so I can change when using
>   function and instead of name, get ["page_id"] or whatever else.

```
function read_pages_array_2 ($param) {
        global $connection;

        $query  = "SELECT * ";
        $query .= "FROM pages ";
        $query .= "ORDER BY id ASC";
        $result = mysqli_query ($connection, $query);
        confirm_query ($result);
        while($result_use = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo $result_use[$param] . "<br/>";

        }
    }

read_pages_array_2("name");
read_pages_array_2("pageID");
```

Isn't this straight forward?

Comment: thank you, I did not realize you can assign a $var to the sqli field.

Comment: so is this what you wanted? @user3136940

Comment: you're welcome. if this was the correct answer, then click on the green tick button to approve it. that's how SO works.

Comment: I am trying, but it says not enough reputation.